# Determine periods of minimum standard deviation in time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have followed many of the posted answers but I have not found anything that works, what works best so far is visual inspection of the time series, but it would be nice to have something quantitative. I am not interested in detecting change points or seasonality, perhaps these might be called steps?

What methodology can provide a list of periods when SD is at its lowest throughout the time series and remains within the lowest standard deviation for a period over n time steps (with n defined previously by the user), I would also like to know the beginning and ending time steps of each low SD period. The low SD could be defined using a rolling SD function. This is to find when the time series is more stable for longer. I am providing a few examples, as you can see some are easier to detect than others. So far using the rolling standard deviation seems to help.

[image]

PS something in R is preferred.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "low" and "certain while," as well as to provide a clearer characterization of "beginning" and "end" of any period.  It might help to explain what the underlying statistical problem is that motivated this question.

Comment: @whuber I tried to make it more specific.

Comment: Maybe look into a dynamic time series model where the variance(s) are modeled as dynamic? (Kalman filtering)